# Input in react - maxLength and font size problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

I am writing RPN calculator in react and I have two problems. First of all: I have two inputs - one for original equation and second for equation transformed to RPN notation. My problems are:
1. I want to limit maximum numbers of characters and
2. I want to font size in input decrease when lenght (in px) of string is larger than input width. It works fine in "original equation" input but something is wrong with "converted" equation.

1. So for limit maximum numbers of chars it's obvious that I have to use maxLength but for some reason it doesn't work. I'm assuming it's because maxLength works if user type something directly in input but in my case input is "readOnly" and values are added by buttons. And I don't know if that is the case or I've made some rookie mistake.
2. As you can see in code I made helper div, in which I put value from input and check both lenghts. In render I check name of input and pass prop depending on name. As I said - it works ok, when I put something in "original equation" but in converted equation I have original font size all the time. Worth of noting is "converted equation" is empty at the beginning and it is filled at the end, when user presses "Solve".

   class InputField extends Component {
       constructor(props) {
           super(props);

   ```
       this.state = {
           fontSize: 38,
           fontSizeConverted: 38
       }
   }
   isOverflow = (input, helper) => {
       if(helper.offsetWidth > input.offsetWidth - 40) {
           return true;
       } else {
           return false;
       }
   }
   componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
       const input = document.querySelector(`input[name=${this.props.name}]`);
       const helper = document.querySelector(`#helper${this.props.name}`);
       let {fontSize} = this.state;
       if(prevProps.value.length < this.props.value.length) {
           if(this.isOverflow(input, helper)) {
               fontSize -= 5;
               this.setState({
                   fontSize,
                   fontSizeConverted: fontSize})
           }
       } else if(prevProps.value.length > this.props.value.length) {
           if(!this.isOverflow(input, helper) && !(this.state.fontSize > 38)) {
               fontSize += 5;
               this.setState({
                   fontSize,
                   fontSizeConverted: fontSize})
           }
       }
   }

   render() {
       return (
           <div>
           <input readOnly maxLength="30" type="text" name={this.props.name} id={this.props.id} className={`calculator__input col-${this.props.col}`}  value={this.props.value} 
           style={{"fontSize": (this.props.name === 'original-equation') ? this.state.fontSize : this.state.fontSizeConverted}} />
           <HelperDiv id={`helper${this.props.name}`} value={this.props.value} 
           font={(this.props.name === 'original-equation') ? this.state.fontSize : this.state.fontSizeConverted} />
           </div>
       )
   }}
   ```